# How can I place a coupon code window on the top of my webpages?

Tags: magento2

Sorry, newbie here! For the convenience of customers, I'd like the coupon code window to appear at the top of web pages, rather than buried in the shopping cart or checkout page. My old website in magento 1.x has it  (please have a look at [www.vitadeals.sg](http://www.vitadeals.sg)), but the developer for our magento 2.x site says it cant be done... Can someone please help shed some light on this for me? Many thanks in advance!